# Summing Euro amounts in Libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with a column full of Euro amounts. This spreadsheet is created from a CSV and the amounts are interpreted as strings (text) rather than as numbers.

[image]

I've been trying to get the sheet to give me the sum of these amounts but no luck. I have failed to find a way to make the sheet understand that these values are numbers. I've used the LEFT function to get just the number part, though that still leaves me with a string.

I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious, which is quite plausible since I am not used to spreadsheets.

Comment: I've now used "text to columns" from the "Data" menu to first split off the euro symbol, and then to split the euros from the cents. That gave me two columns with actual numbers the spreadsheet understood, so I could use SUM. There has to be a better way though...

Comment: How does the CSV look like exactly?

Comment: Remove the euro sign from the field (inorder to get it to format as numbers) and then re-apply it via text formatting tools.

Comment: @tohuwawohu What info do you need? I can't provide the whole sheet as it contains sensitive data

Comment: @Mokubai well yeah. How do I do that for the whole column without editing each field manually?

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw: At least the column containing the amount. Maybe, it's possible to make LO detect the values when importing the CSV data. To test this, a CSV example file is required that's similarly structured (including field delimiters and so on) as your real data.

Comment: Do a find and replace for " €" (space the euro) and replace with nothing (blank field). I don't know where the number formatting tools are in Openoffice

Answer (score 0):

LEFT returns a text value, so it's working as expected. You might put the LEFT function inside VALUE function to convert the value returned by LEFT into a number. This applies to other spreadsheet like Google Sheets.

##### References

- [Documentation/How Tos/Calc: LEFT function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LEFT_function)
- [Documentation/How Tos/Calc: VALUE function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_VALUE_function)